# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Swagger Page Loads via HTTPS but Try It Now uses HTTP and Browser Fails Request

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I just upgraded my project from Swashbuckle 5.6.3 to 6.0.7.  I have made no code changes, but now when attempting to use the Swagger page to test the API, the URL generated by Swagger is not using https even though the page is loaded through https and all the documentation I can find says that it should infer the scheme based on the URL used to load the Swagger page.

Here is the configuration code:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
            c.SwaggerDoc(apiSettings.Version, new OpenApiInfo { Title = apiSettings.Name, Version = apiSettings.Version });

            c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
                Name        = "Authorization",
                In          = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type        = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme      = "bearer",
                Reference   = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" }
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                { new OpenApiSecurityScheme { Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" } }, new List<string>() }
            });
        });
```

and:

```
        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{apiSettings.Version}/swagger.json", $"{apiSettings.Name} {apiSettings.Version}");
        });
```

Is there a new configuration setting to specify the scheme now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is the final code that worked for me.

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapSwagger("/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json", options => {
                options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpRequest) => { });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Does having { } offer any advantages over swagger.Servers.Clear(); ?

Comment: I did try that and for my setup, that did not work.  It's been so long I don't remember why but I seem to recall that caused some kind of error.  Oh, the answer is my last comment on the previous answer.  It caused an ArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

In version 6.0.7, you can change this behavior with the MapSwagger extension method.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    ...
    endpoints.MapSwagger($"/swagger/{apiSettings.Version}/swagger.json", o => 
    {
        o.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
        {
           swagger.Servers.Clear();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have not had a chance to try this yet.  been swamped with other priorities.  I will get to it soon.

Comment: If you update your NuGet again to version 6.1.0, it will probably work as before. You might be interested in this issue on GitHub https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2033

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly the problem I was having.  I will update the nuget package next week.

Comment: I have upgraded to 6.1.2 and the problem still persists.  I'm going to try the code block from this answer.

Comment: The above code does not work, it throws an ArgumentException.  Pattern must contain '{documentName}' parameter (Parameter 'pattern').